# Why is there a 'cache' folder in my /wp-content/uploads folder?

Tags: wordpress, caching, upload, thumbnails

I'm using WordPress 3.5.1. On my web site, the image paths for my post thumbnails, instead of directly linking to the image (i.e. `/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg`) are linking to `/wp-content/uploads/cache/image-slug/12314335235.jpg`

Images 'inserted into posts' show up using their original URLs (i.e. `/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg`). The cache somehow only applies to post thumbnails.

I've searched for why this is happening, but haven't found any solutions. If it makes a difference, I used to have WP Super Cache installed, but it's been a few days since I've properly deactivated and deleted the plugin.

Why would this be happening, and how can I stop it (and pull the images directly)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Enable/Disable Caching in `wp-config.php`.

Another caching mechanism you could take advantage of is the default WordPress object cache. You can enable or disable the native WordPress object cache using your wp-config.php file, like so.

```php
define('WP_CACHE', true);
```

Simply add the above code directly above `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */` using any text editor (Notepad is fine) and save the file.

Comment: do we need the folder when saving a backup of the website?

Comment: define('WP_CACHE', true); is irrelevant. 
Persistent Caching

Prior to WordPress 2.5, data stored using the wp_cache functions was stored persistently if you added define('WP_CACHE', true) to your wp-config.php file.

This is no longer the case, and adding the define will have no effect unless you install a persistent cache plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was malware that had installed itself onto my site, the docs and cache folder where simple a hideout to execute its malicious code (wordfence flagged all the files). I couldn't delete it through the wp-files plugin, so i did it through ssh using the command

cd /home/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs

sudo rm -f -r docs